# Thinkpad T41 - running it as a closet server with the lid closed

Tags: laptop, thinkpad, home-server

I am building a home closet server out of a Thinkpad T41 laptop. In theory it should be more powerful and cheaper to run than a few slices of virtual servers, and reliability is not a big concern for me. I'm throwing Centos on it.

I know a lot of people run home laptop servers, but here's the part that I don't know how to do - how do you run it with the screen closed?

Comment: This may be an overly dumb question, but why don't you just leave the lid open, and turn the laptop the other way ? Cooling also works better that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that your laptop has been configured within CentOS to either standby or hibernate on lid close. You just need to change the lid closed setting to somehting like 'Turn off screen'. This is how I configure my machines because I use my laptops to run Bittorrent overnight.